# Visual Studio: SqlDataSource not seeing ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to add an SqlDataSource for use with a GridView, however, when I try to configure the datasource and select my connection string there are no options. If I try to 'Add new connection' this also does not work. I also tried adding a second connection string, it does not pick this up either.

The connection string is working as I'm using it successfully on another page (just not with an SqlDataSource).

My web.config is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=CAD136\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FDATA2;Integrated Security=True" />
   <add name="DefaultConnection2" connectionString="Data Source=CAD136\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FDATA2;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be [] brackets instead of ():

```
String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString
```

Comment: No that's not the problem, that's the part that is working, it's just not showing as an option in SqlDataSource. I've edited my question to save confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just added the connection string manually in the code view.